# Using different path than /bin/sh for PHP when it needs shell

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, apparmor

I'd like PHP to use an executable at a given path when it needs a shell instead of the default /bin/sh for every situations when it needs a shell (eg mail() function to launch sendmail on UNIX platform, system() function, backtick operator, etc etc). Since I use PHP as apache module, I've tried to change the shell for the www-data user in /etc/passwd, since webserver runs as that user. That didn't help. I've also tried to set SHELL variable in apache config, with SetEnv, but it didn't help either. I'd like to do this, since I want to audit all shell calls done by PHP, to log and/or reject/accept them too. It's not an option to disable PHP functions like system() since existing (cannot be modified) solutions use it. I've already had that "restricted shell" coded in C, I only miss the trick to make PHP to use that binary instead of /bin/sh all the cases when it would need /bin/sh otherwise.

Yes, I've asked this question already related to mail() function, but I realized that I need a much general solution and it's not only mail() related at all, but the problem is the shell usage in general, in many different situations. I've also thought about the possibility to override a path name in apparmor, but I don't think it's possible. The solution to provide a custom chroot "jail" for apache/PHP just for providing a different shell seems to be a huge overkill situation for me :(

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What about to run apache in a chrooted environment?

Comment: Read this [article](http://www.redhat.com/mirrors/LDP/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap29sec254.html). In that chroot jail you could replace the shell by your modified version.

Comment: Yes, I've also mentioned chroot in my question, thanks. Just I feel it's really overkill to have a chroot env just because to set a _single_ string different (the path of used shell), this is a huge wasting of resources and making administration more complex then, etc for me. But if there is no other solution, I have to deal with this for sure ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses [popen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/popen.html) in this case, which generally is hardcoded to use `/bin/sh -c` (see, for example, [glibc's implementation](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iopopen.c;h=b2b88d7f0f9e8500fbe520677042d8e911f94c31;hb=HEAD#l225)).

If setting up a chroot jail truly is not an option, and what AppArmor provides is not sufficient, you may have to modify either PHP or libc.